# How do I use mapReduce in cake php 3.x with pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, mapreduce, cakephp-3.0

I Need to get this to remove X results, lets say for this example I want to remove one result.  But I want all the other results to remain exactly the same.

I am following:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#modifying-results-with-map-reduce

and

https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Collection.Iterator.MapReduce.html

Right now I am trying to achieve, use map reduce and get the exact same results back. So I can later add my conditions to remove the single results.

I need the post reduced results to remain a query object so I can paginate my results(I am not sure this is even possible)

```
$mapper = function ($query, $key, $mapReduce) {
    $everything = 'all';
    $mapReduce->emitIntermediate($query, $everything);
    };

$reducer = function ($query, $status, $mapReduce) {
    $mapReduce->emit($query,$status);
    };

$query = /* ... Make any query on anything ... */

$query->mapReduce($mapper,$reducer);

$paginateforview = $this->paginate($query);
```

This causes my results to just have a count of the number of items in the results, as an array.

I would like an example of how map/reduce reduces nothing or if this is even possible.

I have tried just map, but per the documentation this is a job for map/reduce per map can not remove a result.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

```
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
    return $results->map(function ($row) {
        //Something that unsets the result I tried unset($row)
        return $row;
    });
});
```

In summary I need the mapper to return everything and the reducer to subtract an entire result or a more basic usage example then what is in the cookbook.

NOTES: I realize that editing the database so my query would allow the results to be filtered would be optimal, but right now I am building custom reports and I can not just add things to the database.

Comment: "_**I need the post reduced results to remain a query object**_" - That's not possible. You may want to share your database schema/contents, and elaborate on what exactly you need to retrieve, then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this was possible with afterFind()? Should I assume this is no longer possible in cake. If so I guess I will have to create a bunch of rather elaborate custom finder methods. I don't really need help doing that. It is just if I could subtract results from query one switch statement would replace a large number of controller switches that call custom finders.

Comment: I don't think this was ever possible. You can alter results kinda the same way as with `afterFind()` (`Query::formatResults()` is the successor of the `afterFind` callback with respect to applying things "automatically"), but neither of this would have any effect on the query(object), both happens after the data has already been retrieved, ie after the query has been executed, which means that reducing the dataset will result in the paginator working with a dataset smaller than expected/calculated, which comes with all sorts of complications.

Comment: Maybe you could cheat a little bit using a custom counter that considers possible reduction that would need to be applied, but that would really depend on the data - hard to tell without seeing the full picture.